# How do I show that for small enough $x,$ this equation $f(x) A v(x)= x v(x), f(x)\to 1, x\to 0, ||v(x)||=1, A$ fixed non-zero matrix, can't be true?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I've the following:

- a **fixed** $n \times n$ matrix $A,$ that's a nonzero matrix and has *at least one* non-zero eigenvalue.
- a **scalar function** $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, f(x)\to 1, x\to 0.$
- a **vector valued function** $v: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n, v: x\mapsto v(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n, ||v(x)||=1 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$
- The **equality of vectors** in $\mathbb{R}^n: f(x) A v(x)= x v(x) \forall x$ sufficiently small.

**I'd like to show *rigorously (if possible!)* that for small enough $x,$ this equality won't hold.** Of course if $n=1, A$ is a non-zero scalar, $v(x)= \pm 1,$ so we get $f(x)A(\pm 1) = x (\pm 1) \implies Af(x)= x$ which will have different limits ($A\ne 0$ for the left side and $0$ for the right side) as $x\to 0.$ So in this case we're done. However if $n>1, $ we can't do this. So here's what I tried so far

- Taking norms on both sides doesn't help either, as that'd yield:

$$ |f(x)||A|||||v(x)|| \ge |f(x)|||Av(x)||= |x|||v(x)|| \implies  |f(x)||A|| \ge |x| \implies ||A||\ge 0, x\to 0. $$ This is useless...

- Observing that both sides have *different "growth rates"* w.r.t $x,$ - now I'm not very satisfied with this argument, and if possible, I'd like to rigorize it. I'm considering taking some suitable norms on both sides that'd work, but I'm running into trouble here. More particularly, I'm thinking of something like having some norm inequalities like

*$n_1(Av(x)) \ge n_2(A)n_3(v(x)), n_i's$ are suitable norms in question:

on the left and

*$|x|n_3(v(x))$

on the right, and trying to pass to $x\to 0,$ then canceling out $n_3(v(x))$ from both sides.

Note that: we can try to answer a simplified version of the question assuming $f(x)\equiv 1,$ so trying to show that:

$$A v(x)= x v(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$ won't hold?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why cant $v(x)\equiv 1$ when $n=1$? This won't give two different limits like you said.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur That'd give us $Af(x)=x \forall x$ sufficiently small, but it won't hold in the limit as $x\to 0,$ as the LHS converges to $A\ne 0 (f(x)\to 1),$ and the right hand side converges to $0.$

Comment: If $A=\lambda$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda}x$, this should still be okay, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Not at all, because in this case $f(x)$ does not got to zero,  as hypothesized.

Comment: I misread that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, while $f(x)\to 1$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what is given in the problem at what is the goal. Nonetheless, it is not hard to see if the equality holds and that if $f(x)\neq 0$, then $v(x)$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Being unit vector $v(x)$ has at most $2n$ possibilities. Not only that. The fraction $\frac{x}{f(x)}$ also has at most $n$ values, which are the eigenvalues of $A$.
If you can clarify the set-up, we might be able to figure out what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand these: "Being unit vector v(x)
 has at most $2n$ possibilities (why not infinite possibilities, lying on an infinite compact set, namely the unit sphere?). Not only that. The fraction $x/f(x)$ also has at most $n$ values (again, same question, why? what are these values?) "

What part of the setup is unclear exactly?

Comment: But I guess that my equation shows that a fixed matrix $A$ has an infinite number of eigenvalues $x/f(x),$ which is impossible (following your argument, as there can be at most $n$ distinct eigenvalues). Hence we get a contradiction.